# system app permission issue

Tags: android

I have created a system app signed with firmware key and it is asking for permission from the user when starting the app ex. for Storage / Location. How will I give permission at install time to it won't ask for any permission at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How will I give permission at install time to it won't ask for any
>   permission at runtime?

If you are running your app on OS version >= Android M (API 23) and `targetSdkVersion` is set to >= 23, permissions falling under dangerous category (storage/location permissions fall under this category) have to be granted at run-time. Even System apps are not exempted from this request.

For generic apps only the normal-level permissions are granted at installation time. Since your app is signed with firmware key the advantage it gets is, the normal-level as well as signature-level permissions will be granted at installation time. Refer to [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous) for more details.

Comment: I want to make the app for the embedded device working and oreo and it wont have any screen to accept permission in it .

Comment: @VivekGupta AFAIK best you can do is redirect user to settings screen of your app, where he/she can grant the permission manually. You can keep the question open for sometime in case someone has better option

Comment: app will work as a background and there will not be any user interaction and the device will not be using any screen to handle interactions in it and alternative to get permission from adb etc asi have used adb to give permission but didn't work

Comment: @VivekGupta  `as i have used adb to give permission but didn't work` what error do you get? Are you using `adb shell pm <package-name> android.permission.<permission>`?

Comment: it won't get any error, it still ask for user permission on gui after app run adb shell pm grant com.xxx.xxxx android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.xxxx android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: @VivekGupta just a quick question, you are not requesting read_external_storage right? If are, then grant it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> How will I give permission at install time to it won't ask for any permission at runtime?

**AFAIK** it is not possible if you app **`targetSdkVersion >=23`** because since api 23 user grants all the dangerous  permission at run time not while installing app

its a bad idea to make your targetSdkVersion below 23  because  please read this [**Target API level requirement from late 2018**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)

- Implicit intents for bindService() no longer supported `(Android 5.0)`
- Runtime permissions `(Android 6.0)`
- User-added CAs not trusted by default for secure connections `(Android 7.0)`
- Apps can't access user accounts without explicit user approval `(Android 8.0)`